# Why is it sufficient to consider 'forms' instead of polynomials in the projective case?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

So I am reading through William Fulton's Algebraic Curves and currently I am reading that bit about projective curves. 
Now, when the author discussed about the affine case (in the earlier chapters 1-3), for example, to define affine plane curves in Chapter 3, and all the discussion following he considered $F$ to be a polynomial.

In Chapter 2, he talked about how we can write a polynomial of n variables as a sum of forms and gave a few results related to them. Then when Projective varieties were introduced, he again gave a few result related to forms and from that point onwards, whenever a polynomial $F \in k(\mathbb{P^2}) $ was given it's always assumed to be a form.

Now, what I don't understand is, why is it sufficient to just consider forms in the projective case in contrary to considering polynomial(a sum of forms) in the affine case?

I would appreciate any kind of help/hint(s).

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In projective space, everything is only defined up to scalar multiples. So if you had a non homogeneous polynomial, the question of whether or not a polynomial vanishes at a point of projective space isn't even well defined. For instance, $(0,1,0)$ is a solution to $x + y = 1$. This is the same point in the projective plane as $(0,2,0)$, which is not a solution.

Comment: Hmm...so you're saying that since a polynomial $F \in k[x,y,z]$ if has a zero $(x,y,z) $ then $(ax,ay,az)$ is also a zero of $F$ for all $a \in k{×}$ and also its value at a point $X,Y,Z)$ is the same as it's value at $(aX,aY,aZ)$ and so $F$ clearly has to be a form, right? (That's just an example for $\mathbb{P^{2}}$ but the same thing holds for $\mathbb{P^{n}}$, right?